# Sails production mode searching assets in different path

Tags: sails.js, pug

When I lift the sails application everything is working fine. But when I the sails application in **production** mode, the assets are not loading properly.
Please see the following image.

[In the image /my-course-dashboard is my route. sails is looking for my styles in my-course-dashboard folder instead instead of http://localhost:1337/linker/styles.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJFdX.png)

Am I doing anything wrong. What causes this type of issue.

[Here is my pipeline.js file snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ywR7.png)

I am using sails version 0.12.1. 
Please help. Suggestions are welcome.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: do you have any prefix specified in routes?

Answer (score 0):

- Did you try to set permissions on the folder?
- Remember files are served from `.tmp/public/` folder.